# How to customize dialogs?

Tags: java, swing

I need to make some textFields and other in it and implement some logic. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you want to do?

Comment: I am working in netBeans PLATFORM and need to do some modal window where I can put some values. After click "OK", the new instance of some class is created according to parameters in modal window.

You can imagine it like e.g. "File">"Open project" in netbeans.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Now all you have to do is learn *how*.  Maybe take a class, read a book or use your google-fu.

Comment: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: See also http://platform.netbeans.org/

Answer (score 0):

I dont think I understand your question exactly, but let me try to answer.

Use Action framework in Java. what i see from your expectation is that you need to fire an ACTION (File->Open Project) when you click Ok in your modal dialogue.

Attach a close event to the modal dialogue, inside that event write the logic to call the action that does the same stuff wat the open project action does.

Comment: What I need is: When I create my own action in menu file, then click it in running app, and then modal window appears. I want that some Action shows my own modal window. I need to create couple of custom modal dialogs.